# Fondation 4 navigation via top-bar not rendering dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation 4, the nav-bar is failing to render the dropdown items, even though they are listed in the html

```
    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="/#">Gallery</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/galleria_categoris/1">liposuzione</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvo4/m946D/1/embedded/result/) has the relevant code.  References to the css file and js I believe are correct (in jsfiddle the topbar script is as of line 466); identical file are used in another functioning instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown header has to take class not-click for the items to pop up

```
<li class="has-dropdown  not-click">
```

Not in documentation AFAICT...

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing.  to me has-dropdown should mean the dropdown is active...  Also, where one wants to maintain the same style, but if one removes the anchor tag, you're dealing with a different style. Could be better documented and maybe have has-dropdown p or span inherit has-dropdwon a styles...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle with the foundation 4](http://jsfiddle.net/3bNkX/1/) working topbar with dropdown.

your html structure is correct.. its just your fiddle that didnt work..

```
 <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Main Item 3</a>

    <ul class="dropdown">

      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1c</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1d</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1e</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1f</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
```